# 3 Unknown white slot in laptop motherboard

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard

Can anyone explain it to me what are these slots:

[image: bottom right]

There are 3 white slot, that looks like SATA, is it SATA port?

[image: 3 white slot]

because the [site](http://www.msiwhitebook.com/product_spec.asp?model=MS-16F4) said it should have 2 harddisk slot, but I only found 1 harddisk, there also should be 4 DIMM slot, but I only found 2 piece of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

These ports are [Mini PCI-e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#PCI_Express_Mini_Card) slots, which take a card similar to this:

[image]

Note these can also be an MSATA connection, which are identical but *not* electrically compatible. If your machine is not advertised as having MSATA, it's more likely these are standard Mini PCI-e

Your machine likely does have two SATA ports, however one is usually occupied with an optical drive.

Comment: " which are identical but not electrically compatible" who's idea was that, seems like a big mistake.